# como realizar método comprar en proyecto "billeteraVirtual"

Tags: java, array, metodos

les traigo otro ejercicio de practica en el que tengo dudas de como realizar el método "comprarVenderCriptomonedas",yo lo hice de esa manera como esta en el proyecto pero no me estaría funcionando,en el main hay un menú de opciones de comprar y otro de vender criptos,y otro de informar el saldo de de criptomonedas y este ultimo al probarlo me da 0.0,así que calculo que el método comprar esta mal hecho.Dicho proyecto consta también de un enum en el cual se encuentra la operación COMPRAR Y VENDER así que nose si tal método debo enlazarlo con este enum.
Les dejo algunas clases para que saquen sus conclusiones.

*Clase billeteraVirtual, en donde se encuentra el método en el cual me surge la duda y el método obtenerSaldoActual que para mi esta bien hecho.

```
public class BilleteraVirtual {

private double TIPO_DE_CAMBIO_ETHEREUM = 1859.00;
private int CANTIDAD_DE_CRIPTOMONEDAS_EN_TRANSACCION = 100000;
private String nombreBilletera;
private Transaccion transacciones[];

/*
 * Constructor. Se deben generar los atributos necesarios para el correcto
 * funcionamiento.
 */
public BilleteraVirtual(String nombreBilletera) {
    this.nombreBilletera = nombreBilletera;
    this.transacciones = new Transaccion[CANTIDAD_DE_CRIPTOMONEDAS_EN_TRANSACCION];

}

/**
 * Compra o vende una criptomoneda debiendo indicarse la cantidad. Agrega la
 * transaccion al array de transacciones.
 * 
 * @param cantidad int Cantidad de criptomoneda a comprar
 * @return Verdadero en caso de éxito
 */
public boolean comprarVenderCriptomoneda(int cantidad) {

    for (int i = 0; i < transacciones.length; i++) {
        if (transacciones[i] != null && transacciones[i].getCantidad() == cantidad) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Obtiene el saldo actual calculado en base a las transacciones realizadas
 * 
 * @return Saldo actual o cero
 */
public double obtenerSaldoActual() {
    // TODO: Redondear el resultado para ver solo 2 decimales.
    double saldo = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < transacciones.length; i++) {
        if (transacciones[i] != null) {
            saldo += transacciones[i].getValor();

        }

    }
    return saldo;
}
```

*Aquí la clase "Transaccion" con sus respectivos atributos.

```
public class Transaccion {

private Operacion operacion;
private int cantidad;
private double valor;

/*
 * Constructor. Se deben generar los atributos necesarios para el correcto funcionamiento.
 */
public Transaccion(Operacion operacion, int cantidad, double valor) {
    this.operacion=operacion;
    this.cantidad=cantidad;
    this.valor=valor;
    
}
```

*Y aqui el enum.

public enum Operacion {
COMPRA,
VENTA
}

Comment: No veo que agregues elementos al arreglo `transacciones`. Si este arreglo está vacío, el `for` no arranca, y no suma nada a `saldo`, por lo que se mantiene igual.

Comment: hola, @hector y que tendria que hacer en ese caso,el metodo igualmente esta bien implementado?

Answer (score 0):

en el método ***comprarVenderCriptomoneda***, tenes dos pequeños errores:

El método recibe la cantidad, cuando debería recibir además el tipo de operación y el valor.

```
public boolean comprarVenderCriptomoneda( int cant, Operacion ope, double val ) {
```

el if debiera ser:

```
if( transacciones[i] != null ) {   // si la transacción no fue creada...
    transacciones[i] = new Transacción( ope, cant, val );  // la creamos
```

A tu clase **Transaccion**, le faltan los *getters*.

En el constructor de la clase está esta linea:

```
this.transacciones = new Transaccion[CANTIDAD_DE_CRIPTOMONEDAS_EN_TRANSACCION];
```

Me parece que lo que debes usar algo como **new Transaccion[ cantidadMaximaDeOperaciones ]**.

Comment: hola @MarcePuente genial, gracias por la recomendación!!!